# Arrays in a demo application

Tags: c#, arrays

the thing I'm having the most trouble with is understanding the assignment [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4aJaGug-OR1Wnd4bDlXWXAwQVU/view?usp=sharing). I don't know if it's the fact if it's worded weird or that I'm just stupid. I'm not asking for you to do my assignment for me I just want to know if someone would explain what it's asking for.

UPDATE: apparently I now have to use enum on this so now I'm screwed

Comment: Well, my interpretation of the expected user input is: *f*    (*forward*)  show all the values of the array; *b*    (*backward*) show all the values of the array (in reverse); *q*    (*quit*) - sentinel - quit the program; 0..9 - show the 0th..9th value of the array correspondingly

Comment: Enums are pretty easy to work with. You will need to be a little more specific on what you have to do with the enum though. Do you need to use an enum to decide what option has been chosen? I would suggest you're not screwed at all, just stay calm and try to explain what you've been asked to do with the enums.

Answer (score 2):

Please post the content of the question in your post, i.e. copy and past the text.

Secondly, break it down into sections.

1) You must write a program called IntArrayDemo.

2) The program must contain an array that stores 10 Integers (int).

```
int[] valueArray = new int[10] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
```

3) The program will run until a sentinal value is entered (i.e. you type something that causes the program to quite, say 'q' or '-1').

```
while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Q) {
    ConsoleKey k = Console.ReadKey().Key;
    //Check the key here
}
```

4) The program will have 3 options -

4.1)        View the entire array of integers from 0 to 9 (i.e. forwards)

4.2)        View the entire array of integers from 9 to 0 (i.e. backwards)

4.3)        View a specific location (i.e. you enter a number from 0 to 9, and you are shown the value at that point in the array.

You will need to display some sort of menu on the screen listing the options.

For each of the parts where you need to show the content of the array, use a for loop. `While` loops, or `ForEach` loops should never be used of you have a fixed number of things to iterate over.

> "I don't know if it's the fact if it's worded weird or that I'm just stupid"

In this case, I'm not sure either of those options is accurate. Programming questions are worded quite carefully to force you to think about breaking the task into sections.

In professional programming, you will get all sorts of weirdly worded questions about how something can be done, and you must break down the problem into steps and solve each one.

It's easy to feel a little overwhelmed when you get a single paragraph with a lot of information in it, but breaking it down makes it much more manageable.

Always start with what you know for certain has to be done - in this case, the program must be called IntArrayDemo, so that's a good starting point.

'that stores an array of 10 integers' - good, more information! The program must have an array, which stores `int`s, and can hold 10 values. 
We can infer from this (knowing that arrays start from 0) that our array must count from 0 to 9.

*Enums*

You mention that you need to use enums. Enums are just a data type, which you can define yourself.
Supposing you were writing a server program, and needed to easily see what state it was in. 
The server can be in the following states at any time - Starting, Running, Stopping, Stopped.

You could use a string easily enough - `String state = "Starting"` would do the trick, but a string can hold any value. 
As the server HAS to be in one of those states, an enum is better, as you can specify what those states are.

To declare an enum, you create it as follows...
`enum SERVER_STATE { Starting, Running, Stopping, Stopped };`

Then to use it....
     SERVER_STATE CurrentServerState = SERVER_STATE.Stopped;

```
 if (CurrentServerState == SERVER_STATE.Running) {
     //Do something here only if the enum is set to 'Running'
 }
```

If you wanted to use an enum to decide which option was chosen, you would need to do the following.

1) Get some text of the keyboard (the example using ReadChar above shows you how to do that)

2) Set an enum value based on what was entered

```
enum ACTION = { ListValuesForward, ListValueBackward, ListSpecificValue };
ACTION WhichOption;

//Our ConsoleKey object is called 'k', so....
if (k == ConsoleKey.F) {
    WhichOption = ACTION.ListValuesForward;
}

if (WhichOption == Action.ListValuesForward) {
    //Print out the array forwards
}
```

Knowing that we have an array, that counts from 0 to 9, we can work out that the best loop here is a for loop, as it's controlled by a counter variable.

If you always break a problem down like this, it becomes a lot less daunting.

Hopefully, this should explain the question clearly enough to get you started.